# Threading not working in flask

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

I'm trying to use threading in my flask app, like:

```
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    t = threading.Thread(do_sth_else())
    t.start()
    print('ready to response')
    return render_template('index.html')

def do_sth_else():
    time.sleep(5)
    print('sth else done')
```

When calling `127.0.0.1:5000/index` in the browser, the result in the server console is not what I expected:

```
sth else done
ready to response
```

I want the `do_sth_else()` function to run in some other thread, while the `index()` function go on returning the response right away, which means I should see the above result in defferent order.

So I want to know:

1. Why the `index()` function kept waiting until `do_sth_else()` is finished
2. How do I get the app working as I wanted

Thanks!

Comment: I have change ` t = threading.Thread(do_sth_else())` to ` t = threading.Thread(do_sth_else)`, the result seems right, But i don't know the reason!!!!

Comment: @BlackMamba : @methane 's answer explained the reason, using `t = threading.Thread(target=do_sth_else)` seem to work for me. And if in need of passing parameter to the target function, use the `arg=(parameters)` keyword argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`t = threading.Thread(do_sth_else())` calls `do_sth_else()` and pass it's result to `Thread`.
You should use it like `t = threading.Thread(do_sth_else)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! After looking into the `threading.Thread()` doc, I think I understood how the function work. :)

Answer (score 2):

This example working as you want (tested on Python 3.4.3)

```
from time import sleep
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

# DOCS https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(2)


@app.route('/index')
def index():
    executor.submit(do_sth_else)
    print('ready to response')
    return render_template('index.html')


def do_sth_else():
    print("Task started!")
    sleep(10)
    print("Task is done!")
```

Answer (score 1):

For actual parallelization in Python, you should use the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module to fork multiple processes that execute in parallel.
Python threads provide interleaving, but are in fact executed serially, not in parallel.

This applies to CPython due to the existence of global interpreter lock, otherwise true concurrency is bound to number of cpu's you have

Comment: You should specify that this only applies to `CPython` due to the existence of `global interpreter lock`, otherwise true concurrency is bound to number of cpu's you have. http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/Concurrency.html#no-global-interpreter-lock